# why does javascript not show an alert here?

Tags: javascript, xss

I am trying to learn XSS from Portswigger, and in its lab https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/contexts/lab-javascript-string-angle-brackets-double-quotes-encoded-single-quotes-escaped, my approach yielded the following javascript code.

```html
<script>
  var searchTerms = '\\';
  alert(1);
  \\'';
</script>
```

The problem is that this code shows me an error. But since Javascript is an interpreted language, shouldn't it first show the alert and then show the error?

```html
<script>
  var searchTerms = '\\';
  alert(1);
  whatever;
</script>
```

Like the code snippet above is wrong as well. Here also I get an error, but the alert is also shown. So why not in the first case?

Comment: If it is a syntax error (which is this case), it has to show the syntax error first

Comment: JavaScript isn't interpreted line by line. It first parses the whole script, then it interprets the parsed tokens.

Comment: In the second snippet, the problem isn't a syntax error, it's a semantic error. That isn't detected until it executes the line.

Comment: @Barmar You should add your comment as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are producing in your first code is a [**Syntax Error**](https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/anatomy-of-a-javascript-error). These errors occur when the JavaScript engine is parsing a script and encounters syntactically invalid code. If a JavaScript file contains a syntax error, none of the code in the file will execute.

In your second code you're not having a syntax error but instead a **Semantic Error**, which is why your second script will show the alert.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the script is not working as you expect is that you're assuming that javascript will only look at one line, execute it, and then proceed to next.

However, javascript actually looks at the whole file beforehand. For example, this is demonstrated by the fact that it works to call a function which hasn't even been declared yet, but is declared lower down in the file:

```js
showAlert();

function showAlert() {
  alert("javascript is not executed line by line");
}
```

If javascript only went through the file line by line, it wouldn't know the meaning of `showAlert()` when it first encounters it.

And if a syntax error is found, the code won't run. Note that your second example is different, because it doesn't actually have a syntax error – just the unknown `whatever`.